# App to coordinate timetables

Tags: web-apps, time-management, mobile

Im looking for an app that will overlay many peoples time tables at once to see who has free periods, is busy etc.

Online web / mobile app (Android)

Any recommendations?

Comment: Just to be clear - 1) every user will have to install this new app (it's not looking at existing timetables in other apps, but *might* look at the operating system's calendar) 2)it must work on both iOS and Adroid?

Comment: @Mawg 1) I was thinking of making the timetable myself, i.e taking everyone's rota and manually inputing into the app/web version. 2) Android as that is the only OS I have.                        The plan is to take a screenshot and then post into a group chat

Comment: "Im looking for an app ..." / "I was thinking of making the timetable myself" seems like a contradiction. I think that you need to specify the functionality before going further. Personally, I would have 'phone based apps pushing data to a server. "taking everyone's rota and manually inputing into the app/web version" sounds tedious, and probably ought to be automated.  Since you admit the possibility of a web version, that's probably easiest to implement & is cross platform. Just have users visit your website & input their schedule.

Comment: @Mawg I just need a tool which will produce a master time table for my peers. I don't mind if I have to manually feed the data. I understand the automation aspect but knowing my lazy peers, it's best to do this by myself